# Até que ponto o hardware afeta a programação?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, ciência-da-computação

Hoje em dia o mundo é muito dependente da tecnologia e os benefícios que ela traz. Na maior parte do tempo estamos escrevendo várias linhas de código que serão convertidos em linguagem de máquina e assim dar vida ao que escrevemos. Mas o que torna isso realidade é justamente a máquina, ou também podendo ser chamado de hardware.

Ele é a parte fundamental para realizarmos qualquer operação, mas hoje em dia não parece que a diferença entre saber em que hardware o programa estará rodando é tão relevante assim. Mas não confunda o que eu acabei de dizer com a plataforma em que ele estará rodando, e nem os benefícios que isso traz, eu estou querendo dizer que **parece** que o hardware não tem tanta relevância a ponto dessa questão ser discutida no início de cada projeto, ou pelo menos ser levada com muita consideração, talvez até o ponto de ser feito um outro código-fonte que se adapte para um determinado hardware.

A questão é onde se encontra o limite que isso tudo afeta a programação, já que é possível aplicar, dependendo do projeto, como verdade o que eu disse, dessa maneira ficando difícil definir em que ponto isso realmente importa na hora de programar. Eu poderia dar alguns exemplos como: Um código bem feito e usando as ferramentas certas trazem mais performance e qualidade do que um hardware com tecnologia de ponta? Se tivéssemos a liberdade de ditar como o hardware se comportaria, mesmo sendo mais complicado ou não, o desempenho do programa aumentaria?

O hardware em que um programa determinado irá rodar, afeta de diversas maneiras como ele irá se comportar, mas de maneira **geral**, seja mobile, desktop ou até mesmo um vídeo game, **até que ponto o hardware afeta a programação?** quais as consequências de eu não me preocupar com isso? Usando como um exemplo um programa de desktop, se lembrando da pergunta principal, certas peças do hardware podem fazer eu evitar de escrever várias linhas de código para otimizar o programa? ou fazê-lo rodar mais rápido?

Comment: Faz, e como faz diferença. Eu trabalho com Angular e Ionic, antes trabalhava apenas com PHP e linguagem Web. Angular é mais rápido, logo, o servidor não rpecisa de tanto hardware quanto precisaria pra rodas a mesma aplicação em PHP e Web. Isso é apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Vou ser sincero, e talvez até deixarei muitas pessoas chateadas, mas quem "programa" em "coisas prontas" nem sempre necessariamente programa, geralmente **seguem receitas de bolo**, os FWs dão muitas coisas de mão beijada. Já quem cria os FWs ou os interpretadores de script, esses sim programam, pois eles passam pela parte difícil, que pode incluir entendimento do hardware e APIs do próprio sistema operacional (cada sistema tem as suas próprias APIs para comunicação com o hard) e esses programadores lhes devolvem isto de forma mais simples, o grosso está por baixo fora das vistas da maioria.

Comment: @Guilherme concordo em parte más, programação é uma área muito ampla. Quando se esta por exemplo trabalhando para IoT é comum ser limitado pelo hardware

Comment: Caro @LauroMoraes em que momento disse que não existiam situações que limitavam? O que comentei é simples, existem muitos que não programam de fato, apenas seguem receitas, conheço gente que nem sabe usar if direito e ficam tentando resolver o tratamento de dados retornados em querys e subquerys que muitas vezes são para resolver coisas simples, tem gente que cria ifs complexas e repetidas em sequencia, tem uma série de exemplo que só escrevendo um artigo dará para entender a magnitude do problema. Para resumir, o hard esta sempre presente, mesmo q vc não note, as vezes vc tem um otimo [...]

Comment: [...] equipamento e nem nota que tem recursos do processador que lhe adiantam em muito, o mesmo vale rodar a app em um VM (seja site ou app), os recursos ajudam, é claro que entender eles nem sempre é preciso, mas escrever uma aplicação evitando vazamento de memoria ou loops que não deixam o processador em 100% seria um básico do basico que a pessoa tem que entender... No final das contas o que quero dizer, é que tem muito serviço por ai de "criar app", "criar site", mas tem poucos que se aventuram em criar o q vem por baixo dos panos, esses sim entendem a necessidade do conhecimento. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hoje em dia um programador "comum" não tem a menor preocupação com hardware, em teoria os limites de memória, processamento e armazenamento não serão o calcanhar de aquiles na maioria dos projetos, claro eu tô falando de maneira geral, quando eu digo programador "comum" estou me referindo a programadores trabalhando em projetos e sistemas comerciais básicos...

Pode ser complexo para um programador adaptar seus algoritmos para literalmente tirar leite de pedra de hardwares fracos, isso inevitavelmente vai acontecer com programas mais específicos, quer exemplos de como eu lido com isso em diferentes plataformas? e como realmente mais hardware facilitar a vida de um programador, ou até mesmo deixar o programador mais "preguiçoso"?

Trabalho com processamento de áudio, então imagina que eu tenha hardware de sobra, um desktop por exemplo, imagina que irei criar um simples player de áudio para windows, o player precisa abrir o arquivo de áudio, decodificar no formato que as caixas de som entendam e cuspir os dados na placa de áudio

**(com mt hardware) Minha vida será muito fácil, programador sorrindo e feliz**

Simplesmente nem me preocupo com memória (vou abrir o arquivo inteiro de uma só vez na memória), não tenho problema de processamento (vou poder decodificar o arquivo praticamente de uma só vez), vou poder enviar a matriz ou o array de áudio para a interface de áudio sem precisar criar loops para envio segmentado.(mt mais fácil, sem um impacto gritante para o usuário e deixando a vida do programador infinitamente mais simples)

**(com pouco hardware) é perigoso eu querer decepar a fuça do primeiro q me olhar torto kkk**

Para exemplo um arquivo mp3 decodificado vai ter em média uns `40Mb` tô falando de um arquivo com uns 4min de áudio mp3 em 64kbits amostrado em 44100hz, imagina fazer um player para um leitor mp3... um sistema embarcado igual esse..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagina a dor de cabeça, memoria limitada, processador de no máximo 20 Khz, esse algoritmo será infinitamente mais complexo, precisarei abrir o arquivo em pedaços e decodificar esses pequenos pedaços, um looping que ao mesmo tempo jogue esses pedaços de áudios decodificados em um buffer para só depois enviar aos fones de ouvidos, não tenho processamento e nem memória para fazer tudo de uma só vez, vou precisar criar uma rotina de armazenamento em buffers que contenha um delay específico de tal modo que não afete na saída de áudio (não pode picotar o áudio no fone de ouvido do usuário, então usarei um buffer, uma espécie de FIFO com uma pequena defasagem de tempo, vou precisar disso para consumir os dados de entrada no buffer utilizado para despejo de saída, assim que o buffer encher no tamanho que especifiquei poderei "jogar" o áudio decodificado para os speakers).

O último algoritmo é muito mais eficiente do que o primeiro, praticamente força o desenvolvedor a pensar como usar os poucos recursos disponíveis de maneira consciente para ganho de performance, isso era muito utilizado em desktops da década de 90, a quantidade de memória ram na época era praticamente igual ou inferior ao tamanho de um arquivo de áudio decodificado, não existia outro caminho a não ser pensar em como tentar extrair o máximo do hardware existente....

Ou seja acho que hj em dia um programador q seja alinhado com o Hardware, só para coisas beemmmm específicas ....

Comment: _Ou seja acho que hj em dia um programador q seja alinhado com o Hardware, só para coisas beemmmm específicas_ Isso é de uma tristeza imensa. Se pensar no computador caseiro, na casa do sujeito que fica o dia inteiro vendo baboseira no facebook, não faça diferença, mas em ambiente corporativo, com máquinas virtualizadas ou não, tudo que se aproveita da máquina (dentro do bom senso) representa economia, não só de Hardware, como de energia e recursos para ventilação e refrigeração, e isso não é nada barato. Tem outras muitas questões além dessa.

Comment: Gosto muito de algumas coisas que vc coloca em vários dos seus posts (a ponto de lembrar especificamente do seu username), mas nesse finalzinho acho que faltou visão macro da bola de neve que entramos com "semi-programadores" que não se atentam às coisas básicas (de entender por baixo do capô, coisa que você mesmo entende bem melhor que a média). Penso que pode até ser realidade isso que disse, mas entendo como uma falha dar a entender que é "normal" (ao menos soou assim o último parágrafo) - "programador" que não tem base de hardware anda fazendo MUITO mais estrago do que parece inicialmente.

Comment: https://www.azquotes.com/picture-quotes/quote-one-bad-programmer-can-easily-create-two-new-jobs-a-year-david-parnas-72-10-42.jpg

Answer (score 11):

> Na maior parte do tempo estamos escrevendo várias linhas de código que serão convertidos em linguagem de máquina e assim dar vida ao que escrevemos

Isto acontece com algumas linguagens de programação, não com todas.

> hoje em dia não parece que a diferença entre saber em que hardware o programa estará rodando é tão relevante assim

Para programadores que vão até a página 3 da programação. É verdade que pra muitos cenários isto é verdade e não precisa saber detalhes, mas pelo menos um entendimento básico superficial e genérico é necessário para qualquer programador que use esta palavra com P maiúsculo, ou seja, não é só um criador doe de códigos ou reprodutor de receitas de bolo.

> eu estou querendo dizer que parece que o hardware não tem tanta relevância a ponto dessa questão ser discutida no início de cada projeto

Não é fácil classificar assim o que está querendo dizer, mas de fato detalhes sobre o hardware específico não são muito relevantes para decisões na maioria dos projetos. Pode afetar decisões específicas e detalhes de implementação. Em alguns casos claro que o hardware faz diferença fundamental, mesmo não falando da plataforma, mas de fato a plataforma geral faz mais diferença que o hardware específico.

> até o ponto de ser feito um outro código-fonte que se adapte para um determinado hardware

Sempre é possível fazer isso com bastante poder e flexibilidade, ainda que pode complicar todo desenvolvimento, desde que seja necessário fazer isto. Tem diversas técnicas para obter isto.

> onde se encontra o limite que isso tudo afeta a programação

Depende de cada caso, não dá para responder universalmente.

> Um código bem feito e usando as ferramentas certas trazem mais performance e qualidade do que um hardware com tecnologia de ponta?

Muito genérico responder assim, mas é muito possível um código bem feito ser milhões ou bilhões de vezes mais rápido que um mal feito, em essência nenhum hardware dá uma vantagem tão grande.

> Se tivéssemos a liberdade de ditar como o hardware se comportaria, mesmo sendo mais complicado ou não, a qualidade do programa aumentaria?

Não sei o que isto quer dizer. Qualidade precisaria ser mais bem definida.

> até que ponto o hardware afeta a programação?

Isto é genérico demais.

> quais as consequências de eu não me preocupar com isso?

Vou dar um exemplo: se você vai programar em algo que não tenha armazenamento de massa afeta profundamente como deve programar. Se precisa de persistência terá que usar algo auxiliar por rede. Ou abrir mão da persistência e saber disto. NVRAM pode mudar bastante a forma de persistir os dados desejados.

Outro exemplo em casos de cálculos pesados se você tem GPU pode mudar a forma que vai fazer tudo para aproveitar este recurso.

Dependendo do hardware não pode fazer alguma coisa que exija comportamento de tempo real.

Se você sabe que a aplicação só vai rodar em máquinas muito rápidas pode tomar menos cuidados com certos pontos de implementação que não podem acontecer o mesmo se sabe que vai rodar em máquina pior. Mas o fato de poder ser mais negligente não quer dizer que deva. Só lembrando que hoje a maioria dos programadores são negligentes com isso em quase tudo o que fazem. A maioria nem tem noção disso e usam exemplos de coisas rápidas coisas que são bem lentas, elas perderam a noção.

Nuvem entra nisso ou conta como plataforma? Faz diferença, em alguns casos de forma fundamental como o projeto deve ser feito.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "People who are really serious about software should make their own hardware." Alan Kay - 20/07/1982

Comment: @Peter tem um fundo de verdade nisso, apesar do exagero, pelo menos pros dias de hj :)

Comment: Bem no contrario Maniero! Esta palavra foi usado pelo Steve Jobs em 2007 durante a apresentação do iPhone!! Apple faz o software + o hardware. Se vc tenta desenvolver no Android (o que é o meu caso) vc vai ver que é um inferno porque o software jamais se encaixa de forma coreta com o hardware. A ligação hardware software parece menos importante, mas hoje ela é somente escondida. :)